# Showing Dynamic radio button from database in Static function (jquery) in Asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dynamic, radio-button

I want to show a list of 'Sizes' of Product from database as radio-button in a popup dialog. In the below code i tried it with data-list which is a non static member, so the jquery will not call it because it is calling a static function. Any Solution or Suggestion is appreciated. Please solve my problem

---

```
enter code here
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
 $("#pizzaModal").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            debugger;
            var product = {};
            product.Name = "Pizza";


            $.ajax({
                url: "Default.aspx/GetData1",
                type: "POST",

                data: '{product: ' + JSON.stringify(product) + '}',
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                datafilter: function (data) { return data; },

            });

            return false;
  });
    });


</script>
```

---

enter code here

```
  <asp:DataList ID="dlSize" runat="server" DataKeyField="SizeId">
  <ItemTemplate>
  <input id="radioButton" type="radio" name="rdGroup" value='<%# Eval("SizeName") %>'><%# Eval("SizeName")%></input
  </ItemTemplate>
 <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="khaki" />
   </asp:DataList>
```

---

```
enter code here

public static string GetData1(Product product)
{ 
    cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_SelectProductSize", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", product.Name));
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        dlSize.DataSource = reader;
        dlSize.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Please dont post pictures of your code, but show the actual code itself

Comment: Don't Post source code in images. Edit your question and fix this, otherwise other people will vote to close this question. See: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: make the code behind method a [WebMethod]